# Can't mount many cdrom iso images anymore

Tags: mount, 16.10, cd-image

I just noticed today that many of my iso rips that always mounted without issue can't be mounted anymore.

I can still mount some isos, with `sudo mount -o loop mycd.iso /mnt/iso`, but most no longer work. They give the "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock..." error.

I'm not sure why this would happen. For instance, and old Windows ME image I ripped no longer mounts, but a win98 image mounts just fine. Only a few of my pc games work. None of my Diablo 2 rips work anymore, and I've used those hundreds of times.

What could have changed? Is there a 32/64-bit mismatch? Could moving the data from ext3 to btrfs caused a problem? Are they using some encoding that isn't supported in recent Ubuntus? I'd rather not have to re-rip my CD/DVD collection.